# Slide the legs of a table

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow, edit-mode

Here is very simple model of a "table":

[image]

How could I easily slide the selected part closer to the inside, i.e. move it along the X axis? If I just move it, the top part will obviously be distorted:

[image]

Instead, I would like the top part to protrude like this:

[image]

How would you do this?

Comment: I would move this leg including the top of the table, and later extrude the side face of the top of the table

Comment: That's a possibility. But if I want to keep the top part exactly the same size, I would have to resort to using guides and snapping again. Is there no easier way? I think, if I could somehow "convert" the left most edge (between the top and the leg) to a face of zero area, I could move the leg without distorting the rest. I can't find a command like this though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest to use the vertex rip and then fill as shown in the animation below.
[image: Rip and Fill]

Comment: once ripped, you can select just one vertex and then select all linked vertices with Ctl+L

Comment: I only ripped two of the legs' verts, not all top four, otherwise this would have been true :)     ( which is why you only need to recreate one face to have a watertight mesh again)

Comment: Cool. Probably there is no simpler solution for this particular case. How did you select the edges around the hole without using the mouse (or did I just not see it?)

Comment: Alt + right mouse button on the edges (the gif recorder misbehaved, so the mouse cursor is offset from where it actually was)

Answer (score 3):

Press <kbd>P</kbd> key with the table leg selected and choose Selection,

[image]

to separate it by selection and then <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the table and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to join them back together, now you can move it however you like.

-*don't forget to exit the edit mode of the table before you join them*

Answer (score 2):

- Select the side face of the table top
  [image]
- <kbd>Shift S</kbd> and 'Cursor to selected'
  [image]
- Move the leg including the table top on the X-axis
  [image]
- Make 3d cursor as pivot point for later extruding on the X-axis
  [image]
- Extrude the side face of the table top and scale to 0 on the X-axis
  [image]